# Convert decimal number to binary in specified range

Tags: matlab

I wand to convert decimal numbers 0-7 in 3 bits. I have problem with 0, 1, 2 and 3

```
b = dec2bin(3)

b =

  11
```

Comment: Have you specified a width according to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The function [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html?refresh=true) has a input parameter which allows you to set the minimal number of bits.

Comment: I want in every convert 3 bits. How to specify?